# How would I do a mapped async transform of a nested structure?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Say I have some code that looks like this:

```js
const myObject = {
   outerList : [
      {
         innerList: [
            1, 2, 3
         ]
      }, 
      {
         innerList: [
            2, 4, 6
         ]
      }
   ]
}; 

async function asyncTransform(i) {  
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(i+1); 
      }, Math.random()* 1000); 
    }); 
}

async function asyncTransformNestedObject(obj) {
   //??? 
}

asyncTransformNestedObject(myObject).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

And I want to transform the object to this:

```
{
   outerList : [
      {
         innerList: [
            2, 3, 4
         ]
      }, 
      {
         innerList: [
            3, 5, 7
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

What would the best way to do this be - ideally in a way where the async functions run simultaneously.

Comment: do we really need an async function here?

Comment: @brk Yes. This is just an example. In real life, these are API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up going with:

It's pretty straight forward when you think about it:

A Promise.all of a Promise.all is going to resolve at the maximum time of all the promises.

```js
const myObject = {
   outerList : [
      {
         innerList: [
            1, 2, 3
         ]
      }, 
      {
         innerList: [
            2, 4, 6
         ]
      }
   ]
}; 

async function asyncTransform(i) {  
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(i+1); 
      }, Math.random()* 1000); 
    }); 
}

async function transformInnerObj(innerObj) {    
    const newInnerList = await Promise.all(innerObj.innerList.map(i => asyncTransform(i))); 
    return {
      innerList: newInnerList
    }; 
}

async function asyncTransformNestedObject(obj) {
   
   const newOuterList = await Promise.all(obj.outerList.map(innerObj =>       transformInnerObj(innerObj)));                                           
   return {
      outerList:  newOuterList                                  
   }; 
}

asyncTransformNestedObject(myObject).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Minor: Functions that explicitly return a `Promise`, like `asyncTransform` don't need to be marked as `async`.

Answer (score 1):

- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each inner element to a Promise returned by `asyncTransform` and then pass that array to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
- Then `Promise.all` each `Promise.all` created in step 1.

Here's an example:

```js
const myObject = {
  outerList : [
    {
      innerList: [
        1, 2, 3
      ]
    }, 
    {
      innerList: [
        2, 4, 6
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function asyncTransform(i) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(i + 1), 50))
}

function asyncTransformNestedObject(obj) {    
  const innerLists = obj.outerList.map(el => {
    return Promise.all(el.innerList.map(asyncTransform))
      .then(results => el.innerList = results)
  })
  
  return Promise.all(innerLists)
    .then((results, i) => obj.outerList.map((el, i) => ({ 
        ...el, 
        innerList: results[i] 
      })))
}


asyncTransformNestedObject(myObject).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Note that you aren't reproducing the structure of the original object properly.

Comment: True, added a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using a recursive setTimeout/requestAnimationFrame in ES5, but if you insist on async function, this seems to do the trick:

```
     async function convert(arr,i = 0){
            if(!arr[i]){return arr}
            await arr[i].innerList.reduce((ac,d,i,a) => ++a[i],(async function(){}()));
            return convert(arr,++i);
        }

    convert(myObject.outerList);

//myObject
    "[
        {
            "innerList": [
                2,
                3,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "innerList": [
                3,
                5,
                7
            ]
        }
    ]"
```

You didn't specify anything about mutating the original object, so I changed it in place. I also returned the innerArray, you could have returned the object itself insteand and use await to store in a variable.

Comment: Not my downvote, but that's some pretty cryptic code.

Comment: @dwjohnston, I understand, np. That's why I said I'd solve with recursive ES5. I saw that you kinda emphasized async functions, so I wondered whether it'd be possible to only use async/await. The reduce part is to force the line to return a resolved Promise with undefined and await it so that all array elements are incremented, if that's the part that was cryptic.